# Cannot resolve symbol при указании обработчика события для кнопки

Tags: java, javafx

Работаю с javaFX. Произвожу попытку указания метода обработки события для кнопки. Выдается ошибка Cannot resolve symbol actionOk. Честно говоря, не понимаю в чем дело. fx:controller указан, методы созданы, fxml файл видит EditDialogController в котором находятся данные методы (Intellij Idea видит баттоны и поля и я могу двойным кликом переходить по ним). Рядом с этим проблемным кодом находится основной контроллер и основной фрейм, который сделан по образу и подобию и прекрасно работает. Подскажите, что я пропустил.
Файл FXML

```
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" 
minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="400.0" 
xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="sample.EditDialogController">
<left>
  <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
     <children>
        <Label text="Full name">
           <VBox.margin>
              <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
           </VBox.margin>
        </Label>
        <Label text="Phone">
           <VBox.margin>
              <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="17.0" />
           </VBox.margin>
        </Label>
     </children>
     <BorderPane.margin>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
     </BorderPane.margin>
  </VBox>
</left>
<center>
  <VBox minWidth="200.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" 
BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
     <children>
        <TextField fx:id="fieldFullName">
           <VBox.margin>
              <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
           </VBox.margin>
        </TextField>
        <TextField fx:id="fieldPhone">
           <VBox.margin>
              <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
           </VBox.margin>
        </TextField>
     </children>
     <BorderPane.margin>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
     </BorderPane.margin>
  </VBox>
</center>
<right>
  <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
     <children>
        <Button fx:id="buttonOkName" defaultButton="true" 
mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#actionOk" prefHeight="25.0" 
prefWidth="51.0" text="OK">
           <VBox.margin>
              <Insets bottom="5.0" left="25.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
           </VBox.margin>
        </Button>
        <Button fx:id="buttonPhoneCalcel" cancelButton="true" 
mnemonicParsing="false"  text="Cancel">
           <VBox.margin>
              <Insets bottom="5.0" left="25.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
           </VBox.margin>
        </Button>
     </children>
     <BorderPane.margin>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
     </BorderPane.margin>
  </VBox>
</right>
</BorderPane>
```

И следом соответственно файл контроллера:
    package sample;

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class EditDialogController
{
@FXML
public Button buttonOkName;

@FXML
public Button buttonPhoneCalcel;

@FXML
public TextField fieldFullName;

@FXML
public TextField fieldPhone;

public Person person;

public void actionClose(ActionEvent actionEvent)
{

}

public void setPerson(Person person)
{
   this.person = person;

   fieldFullName.setText(person.getFullName());
   fieldPhone.setText(person.getPhone());

}


public void actionOk(ActionEvent actionEvent)
{

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблема заключается в этой строчке

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
```

Вы импортируете `ActionEvent` из пакета `java.awt` , а нужный вам `ActionEvent` лежит в пакете `javafx.event`